# Validate number Input

Tags: java, android, validation

I am working on a validation problem, and i need to come up with a solution for validation.

The user is supposed to enter a password, which is a 4 digit number. The validation rules applied to it should be.

1. Password cannot be continuous numbers, ie, 1234 or 9876
2. It cannot be duplicate, ie, 1111, 2222
3. It cannot be continuous series of three numbers, ie, 1345, 9765
4. It cannot be a same number triplet, ie, 2444, 1115.

Now, what i've done so far is: 
1. I tried using this formula, which was given in another solution, but it didn't help. 
Break the input into an int[] and get first & last items from it, then apply the validation.

A[length-1] - A[0] = A.length-1
This works for continuous numbers, 1234, 9876, but it breaks when i enter 1324, which is valid.

Then, to validate duplicates i thought of using a set, entering the numbers in the set, then checking the size of the set, like 1111, 2222. But, it fails again in case 1212, which is a valid input.

Although, this can be solved by adding or subtracting 1 from every number, and checking if its continuous, but i am looking for something other that that. That solution would be my last approach.

Solution in java appreciated. If not, then simple pseudo code is also fine. 
Assume that only numbers can be given as input.

UPDATE: 
Sorry guys, i don't take SO as a way to do my homework, but i thought the information was enough. Anyways, here's what i had managed so far,

```
private boolean checkFirstOrderAscendingDescending(int[] array, int length) {
        // to handle passwords like 1234, 9876
        int arrayItemOne = array[0];
        int arrayItemLast = array[length - 1];

        if (Math.abs(arrayItemLast - arrayItemOne) == length - 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

private boolean checkDuplicates(int[] array, int length) {
        // to handle passwords like 1112, 9998
        int arrayItemOne = array[0];
        int arrayItemTwo = array[1];
        int arrayItemThree = array[2];

        if (arrayItemOne == arrayItemTwo && arrayItemTwo == arrayItemThree) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The check duplicates method can be extended to check duplicates in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd index of the array. Before calling these methods, null check is placed on the array. Also, there is a guarantee that the length of the array will always be 4, so requesting specific index will never give ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

I hope the info given now is sufficient.

Comment: can you show us the code you already did, so we don't do all your homework?

Comment: As you should know with your rep, SO is not a coding service. Even worse, you are asking the community to do your homework. Please do an effort, post your code and ask a more specific problem you encounter.

Comment: ironically (and off-topic), from a brute forcing perspective these all make the actual password selection weaker.

Comment: @vibhor_shri if your question is answered please mark it as such.

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret, i have not been able to test it. I'll do it shortly, and will update.

Comment: @vibhor_shri no problem, just wanna make sure you got what you needed - if it's not working feel free to ask

Comment: @Olaia, i never implied that the community do my work. If the question fell short on code, then i've updated it. And i guess, for that u have already down voted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my solution. please don't treat SO as a way to get around your homework

```
private static final int MAXIMUM_DUPLICATES = 2;
private static final int MAXIMUM_SERIES = 2;
private static final int SERIES_DIRECTION_ASCENDING = 0x42;
private static final int SERIES_DIRECTION_DESCENDING = ~SERIES_DIRECTION_ASCENDING;
public static boolean isPasswordValid(String pwd) {
    char lastChar = '\0';
    int duplicateCount = 1;
    int seriesCount = 1;
    int seriesDirection = 0; 

    char[] chars = pwd.toCharArray();
    for(char c : chars) {
        //skip the first character
        if(lastChar > 0) {
            if(lastChar == c)
                duplicateCount++;
            else
                duplicateCount = 1;

            if(lastChar == c+1) {
                //was the previous char of the same series? if not then reset the seriesCount
                if(seriesDirection != SERIES_DIRECTION_ASCENDING) {
                    seriesCount = 1;
                    seriesDirection = SERIES_DIRECTION_ASCENDING;
                }

                seriesCount++;
            } else if(lastChar == c-1) {
                if(seriesDirection != SERIES_DIRECTION_DESCENDING) {
                    seriesCount = 1;
                    seriesDirection = SERIES_DIRECTION_DESCENDING;
                }

                seriesCount++;
            } else {
                seriesCount = 1;
            }

            //are there more duplicates then are allowed?
            if(duplicateCount > MAXIMUM_DUPLICATES)
                return false;

            //is there a longer series then allowed?
            if(seriesCount > MAXIMUM_SERIES)
                return false;
        }

        //save the last character
        lastChar = c;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and here my way to check it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Boolean> inputsAndExpectedResults = new HashMap<>();

    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("1234", false);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("4321", false);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("1122", true);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("8143", true);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("1265", true);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("9233", true);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("9137", true);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("2222", false);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("4333", false);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("5421", true);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("6667", false);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("4569", false);
    inputsAndExpectedResults.put("1272", true);

    Set<String> keySet = inputsAndExpectedResults.keySet();
    for(String key : keySet) {
        Boolean expectedValue = inputsAndExpectedResults.get(key);

        boolean result = isPasswordValid(key);
        String output = String.format("isPasswordValid(%s) returned %b expected %b", key, result, expectedValue);
        if(expectedValue.equals(result))
            System.out.println(output);
        else
            System.err.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: it does work, @Japu_D_Cret. thanks for the solution